# Problemas com tokens guardados em session?

Tags: php, session, token

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em `php` e na parte de autenticação tenho o seguinte código :

```
    public function chamaApi(){
        // chamada na api via curl  
        $profile = json_decode($response);

        if($profile->error != true){
           self::openSession($profile->data->api_key);
        }
    }
```

`$profile` obtém o resultado retornado pela `API`, (ID do usuário que fez login, token de acesso da api, nome e email).

```
public function openSession($profile){
   $_SESSION['profile'] = $profile;
}
```

Minha dúvida é se há algum problema em gerenciar a `session` utilizando o `token` de acesso da `API` (único para cada usuário). E se existir algum problema, qual seria a melhor forma de gerenciar a session para segurança da aplicação?

PS: não uso framework!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara, se o valor do token não está visível no cookie, então não tem problema. Como esse valor está salvo no server-side, o usuário não tem acesso e consequentemente não é um problema.

No modo padrão de autenticação, geralmente colocamos o id do usuário diretamente dentro da sessão, ele sozinho é capaz de dar acesso a tudo que aquele específico usuário pode fazer.

A mesma coisa aconteceria com esse token, a diferença é que ao invés de um id, você está usando uma sequência de caracteres aleatória que conecta com a API.

O mais importante mesmo é que você esteja trabalhando esse gerenciamento de sessão da forma mais segura possível, evitando [session hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack), etc. Porque isso sim pode ser um problema.

De uma forma muito comum, uma extensão pode pegar o valor do cookie e passar pra outro usuário, e ele pode setar o cookie diretamente no site e ter acesso a aquilo que o usuário estava acessando de outra máquina.

---

Se você estiver trabalhando com o Composer na sua aplicação, eu recomendo que conheça o componente [HttpFoundation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/index.html) do Symfony. Ele tem várias utilidades para lidar com requisições, etc, mas o que vejo de mais foda nele é o gerenciamento de sessões. É o mesmo usado no Framework em si e é muito seguro e simples de usar.

***PS:*** você não precisa usar o framework completo para usar esse componente.